# Drop-down List is not getting closed on clicking other drop-down input field in Angular-6

Tags: angular-components, angular6

I have created a component of custom drop down list, for re-use it in another components like form.

I am using two components

1) Form (Parent Component)
   2) drop-down (Child Component)

Form component has two drop-down  list first is Country Name list and second is Cities Name list. The data is sending from parent component to make the drop down-list.
The expected behaviour is as follows.

1) On clicking the Country input field, the list of Country Names drop-down should be open
  2) On clicking the Country input field again, the drop-down should be hide
  3) On clicking any where in page the drop-down should hide.
  4) On clicking another drop-down input field the relevant drop-down list should be open and same time other drop-down should be hide.

Every-thing is working fine except following.

If Country down-list is already opened and same time I click on Cities drop-down input field the relevant Cities drop-down get opened. 
  But the Country drop-down list is not getting hiding. The expectation is Country drop-down list should hide.

Comment: I will suggest you to create renderer 2 on country down list. Listen click event of cities drop down, same time you can remove class 'open' from first drop down means country drop down.

Comment: Thanks Protozoid,
I tried renderer 2. It works.

Comment: Always welcome.. BTW its androidOnHigh :D